# Is it possible to use embedded ruby in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, embedded-ruby

I used embedded Ruby in fixtures to create n objects:

```
<% 30.times do |n| %>
micropost_<%= n %>:
  content: <%= Faker::Lorem.sentence(5) %>
  created_at: <%= 42.days.ago %>
  user: michael
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to use embedded Ruby in tests, in order to test the above n objects? 
 I would need to iterate over each object and make assertions as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE microposts")
(1..30).each do |num|
  assert_nil microposts(:micropost_<%= num %>)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way of doing this, but a simple solution would be as follows.

Instead of:

```
assert_nil microposts(:micropost_<%= num %>)
```

have:

```
assert_nil microposts("micropost_#{num}".to_sym)
```

Edit:

To answer your question. No, you can't use an embedded ruby escape in a .rb file. It's already ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby in RSpec or MiniTest (or whatever test framework) since the tests are just Ruby.

Comment: Can I use in texts the <% or <%= syntax that is usually available in erb files?

Comment: That's ERB -- you shouldn't have to use it... not sure why you're need that. You can interpolate text using something like `puts my var: #{my_var}"` or similar.